# why is filebeat unable to connect to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I am trying to send a log4net log to logstash to get parsed and then end up in elasticsearch. I have added the port to the windows firewall security setting and allow all connection, both to 5044 and 9600.

In the filebeat log, i get this error

```
pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://[http://hostname:5044]:5044)): lookup http://hostname:5044: no such host
```

**Filebeat.yml (Logstash section)**

```
#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["http://hostname:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Processors =====================================
```

**Logstash.yml**

I have set the http.host to 0.0.0.0

```
# ------------ Metrics Settings --------------
#
# Bind address for the metrics REST endpoint
#
 http.host: "0.0.0.0"
#
# Bind port for the metrics REST endpoint, this option also accept a range
# (9600-9700) and logstash will pick up the first available ports.
#
# http.port: 9600-9700
```

**Logstash Filter Config**

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
  }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "log4net" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{NUMBER:threadid}\] %{WORD:level}\s*%{DATA:class} \[%{DATA:NDC}\]\s+-\s+%{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
        }
        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss"]
            remove_field => ["timestamp"]
        }
        mutate {
            update => {
                "type" => "log4net-logs"
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://hostname:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

Comment: `http://hostname:5044: no such host` which means that `hostname` cannot be resolved properly. Are you sure it's a valid host name?

Comment: if you're sure on the host name then maybe try using the fully qualified domain name

Comment: @Val I am using a valid host name, its the same hostname i added to the ElaststicSearch host in the logstash configuration (http://hostname:9200) and filebeat seems to send data to elasticsearch without a problem. but the same hostname with port 5044 isnt working for logstash

Comment: Is everything running on the same host (Filebeat, Logstash, ES)? How does your Logstash pipeline (input/filter/output) configuration look like?

Comment: @Val Filebeat is running locally and pushing to a remote server. ElasticSearch and Logstash are both installed on that remote server.. hence the hostname being the same for both, and i have allowed incoming traffic to port 9200, 5044, 9600 which are ports for elasticsearch and logstash

Comment: How does your Logstash pipeline (input/filter/output) configuration look like?

Comment: @Val I have updated the post withe logstash filter conf file

Comment: See the answer below by @AdrianDr, the `http://` scheme must be removed because [Beats communicates with Logstash via the lumberjack protocol](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html) which is not HTTP but runs over TCP directly.

Comment: @Val, thanks for that, i think that got me a litter closer, however i get a different error now, i have explained it under AdrianDr answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using hostname:

```
hosts: ["hostname:5044"]
```

Comment: now i get Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://hostname:5044)): dial tcp hostIp:5044: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: I think its because Logstash isnt listening on that port, i do have the port as an inbound rule set to allow all incoming connection, i can see that 9600 is listening but not 5044

Comment: @ifelabolz Can you restart Logstash with `--log.level=debug` and update your question with the logs you get

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Adrian Dr try using:

```
hosts: ["hostname:5044"]
```

But also bind logstash to a single port:

```
http.port: 9600
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error. It's because you mention protocol.

You have to remove 'http' from hosts field.

```
hosts: ["somename.com:5044"]
```

or ip

```
hosts: ["10.10.10.1:5044"]
```